# How to add field separator based on headers length?

Tags: awk, field

I'm trying to add a delimiter to the following text format (actual file has many more fields).

What I see is the length of each field is given by the length of each underscores blocks `------------` that are below each header.

Input:

```
NAME                  ADDRESS                                                      PHONE       
--------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------ ------------
CLARK KENT            344 Clinton Street, Apartment 3D, midtown Metropolis         11111111    
TONY STARK            Malibu Point 10880, 902XX                                    22222222    
PETER PARKER          15th Street, Queens, New York City, New York                 33333333
```

Output desired:

```
NAME                 |ADDRESS                                                     |PHONE       
CLARK KENT           |344 Clinton Street, Apartment 3D, midtown Metropolis        |11111111    
TONY STARK           |Malibu Point 10880, 902XX                                   |22222222    
PETER PARKER         |15th Street, Queens, New York City, New York                |33333333
```

My attempt so far it prints the lenght of each header but I don't know how to add the field separator `|` at the position:

```
$ awk 'FNR == 2 {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {print length($i)}}'
21
60
12
```

Please some help on this

Comment: Yes, there are trailing spaces at the end And Thanks so much for your help. I know your solutions work if the input would be correctly formatted, but I've seen some "bugs" in some fiels that between names and lastnames have more than one or 2 spaces, so the safest logic I see is based on underscores headers length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in place `FIELDWIDTHS`

```
 $ awk -v OFS='|' 'NR==1 {h=$0; next} 
                   NR==2 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) f=f FS 1+length($i); 
                          FIELDWIDTHS=f; 
                          $0=h} 
                         {$1=$1}1' file

NAME                  |ADDRESS                                                      |PHONE
CLARK KENT            |344 Clinton Street, Apartment 3D, midtown Metropolis         |11111111
TONY STARK            |Malibu Point 10880, 902XX                                    |22222222
PETER PARKER          |15th Street, Queens, New York City, New York                 |33333333
```

Comment: wthout being an expert, I see this solution works and is the shortest one. Thank so much. The inly issue is adding an extra "|" at the end

Answer (score 3):

You may use this awk that will with any version of `awk`:

```sh
awk -v OFS='|' '
NR == 1 {
   h = $0
   next
}
NR == 2 {
   for(i=1; i<NF; i++)
      w[i] = (i == 1 ? 1 : w[i-1] + 1) + length($i)
   $0 = h
}
{
   for(i=1; i<=length(w); i++)
     $0 = substr($0, 1, w[i]) "|" substr($0, w[i]+i)
} 1' file

NAME                  |ADDRESS                                                     |PHONE
CLARK KENT            |344 Clinton Street, Apartment 3D, midtown Metropolis        |11111111
TONY STARK            |Malibu Point 10880, 902XX                                   |22222222
PETER PARKER          |15th Street, Queens, New York City, New York                |33333333
```

---

**Old solutions based on sample data provided**

You may try this `sed` that matches substring with 2+ whitespaces followed by 1 non-whitespace and inserts `|` between them:

```sh
sed -nE '/^-{3,}/! {s/([[:blank:]]{2,})([^[:blank:]])/\1|\2/gp;}' file

NAME                  |ADDRESS                                                      |PHONE
CLARK KENT            |344 Clinton Street, Apartment 3D, midtown Metropolis         |11111111
TONY STARK            |Malibu Point 10880, 902XX                                    |22222222
PETER PARKER          |15th Street, Queens, New York City, New York                 |33333333
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I know your solutions work if the input would be correctly formatted, but I've seen some "bugs" in some fiels that between names and lastnames have more than one or 2 spaces, so the safest logic I see is based on underscores headers length.

Comment: You guys both get a nod on this one. I was working with gawk's FIELDWIDTHS, but Glenn won that race. sed should have been my first thought.

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU awk

```sh
wid=$(awk '
  NR == 2 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%d ", 1 + length($i)
    exit
  }
' file)

gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS="$wid" '
  NR != 2 {
    for (i=1; i<NF; i++) printf "%s|", $i
    print $NF
  }
' file
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and tme, your solution it works

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for FIELDWIDTHS:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="|" }
NR==1 { hdr=$0; next }
NR==2 {
    nf = split($0,f)
    for (i=1; i<=nf; i++) {
        FIELDWIDTHS = (i>1 ? FIELDWIDTHS " 1 " : "") length(f[i])
    }
    $0 = hdr
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) {
        printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
NAME                 |ADDRESS                                                     |PHONE
CLARK KENT           |344 Clinton Street, Apartment 3D, midtown Metropolis        |11111111
TONY STARK           |Malibu Point 10880, 902XX                                   |22222222
PETER PARKER         |15th Street, Queens, New York City, New York                |33333333
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it works excellent, the only thing is adding an extra "|" at the end, I thinks is because the input it has spaces at the end of each line